# C++ - Throw Erorr Message

Tags: c++, throw

The main() function should display an appropriate
thrown error message if non-numeric or negative values are entered for any of
the data members.

can someone help me to write the main function

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class RealEstate
{
private:
    int price;
    int bedroomNumb;
    int bathsNumb;

public:
    RealEstate(int p, int bed, int bath)
    {
        price = p;
        bedroomNumb = bed;
        bathsNumb = bath;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const RealEstate &r);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, RealEstate &r);
};

istream &operator>>(istream &in, RealEstate &r)
{
    cout << "Enter Real Estate Price: ";
    in >> r.price;
    cout << "Enter Numbers of Bedroom: ";
    in >> r.bedroomNumb;
    cout << "Enter Numbers of Baths: ";
    in >> r.bathsNumb;

    return in;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const RealEstate &r)
{
    out << "Price: " << r.price << endl;
    out << "Bedroom: " << r.bedroomNumb << endl;
    out << "Baths: " << r.bathsNumb << endl;

    return out;
}

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't throw anything?

Comment: exceptions are thrown where the exceptional situation occurs and catched somewhere up the call stack (or not). Only modifiying `main` to throw exceptions doesnt really make sense here. Is it possible that other code is supposed to throw exceptions that you are then supposed to catch in `main`?

Comment: have some function add to my code ?  i mean function that will be thrown fucntion ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you would like to have a few try and catches in your main(), and throws in the functions that are accepting user input. If that is the case, you should definitely make use of the throw keyword within your functions. In your main, you would

```cpp
int main(){
    try{
       function() //note that the function you are calling here should throw an error of type char* and throw this error if the number input by the user is negative and non-numeric. 
    }catch(const char* msg)
}
```

That is a brief explanation of how you would implement Error Handling (given the program and information you have provided).

Hope this helps!